# Can't use migrations in EF Core: "42P07: relation "AspNetRoles" already exists"

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have strange issue which I can't find solution for.

The stack is: NET Core 2, EF, PostgreSQL.
I use .NET Core Identity with `User : IdentityUser` to extend base user model with additional fields.

After I create first migration, drop whole database and try to `dotnet ef database update` I always get an error: `42P07: relation "AspNetRoles" already exists`

Even with this error, the database and tables are created but it makes migrations useless as it does not save applied migrations so I can't update DB with following changes...

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[200102]
>         Failed executing DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>         CREATE TABLE "AspNetRoles" (
>             "Id" text NOT NULL,
>             "ConcurrencyStamp" text NULL,
>             "Name" varchar(256) NULL,
>             "NormalizedName" varchar(256) NULL,
>             CONSTRAINT "PK_AspNetRoles" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
>         ); Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P07: relation "AspNetRoles" already exists    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.d__148.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.d__147.MoveNext()

Comment: Did you change some stuff after migration was created ? that action can trigger a similar error

Comment: No. Nothing. I have tried many times deleting migrations and creating them again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason was pretty simple.
I was calling `EnsureCreated` in `Startup.cs` which was getting conflict with migrations as working different way.
Thankfully EF Core owners made it clear for me on GitHub.

So to summarize - if you want to use Migrations, you can't use EnsureCreated.

Answer (score 2):

I was doing something really dumb!  I copied the connection string from another micro service and it had the wrong Database in the connection string - that database already had the table that the error was complaining about!  Block Copy strikes again!

Comment: I hate when my code does what i say and not what i want...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, what worked for me was that I deleted the whole database (I did not have any important information there yet) and when I generated database with new name, then added Migrations again and then did database update.

Comment: This might be a solution, but I no one wants to lose data.