# .Net Core - Error 42P07 in Migration exist database pgSQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, .net-core

I'm having trouble migrating to an existing database,

This is my Error:

> An error occurred while starting the application. PostgresException:
>   42P07: relation "Contaminacao" already exists
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector+<>c__DisplayClass161_0+<g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
>
> PostgresException: 42P07: relation "Contaminacao" already exists

Image in VS2017:
[image]

The problem occurs with the entity 'Contaminacao' and 'Contaminacao_Regra', where 'Contaminacao_Regra' has two 'Contamination' fk. Look:

'Contaminacao'

```
public class Contaminacao
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo {0} é obrigatório")] // {0} é o campo Name
        [StringLength(8, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter entre {2} a {1} caracteres")]
        public string Cor { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
        [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter entre {2} a {1} caracteres")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Contaminacao_Regra> Anterior_Contaminacao_Regras { get; set; } = new List<Contaminacao_Regra>();
        public virtual ICollection<Contaminacao_Regra> Proxima_Contaminacao_Regras { get; set; } = new List<Contaminacao_Regra>();

        public Contaminacao()
        {
        }

        public Contaminacao(int id, string cor, string descricao)
        {
            Id = id;
            Cor = cor;
            Descricao = descricao;
        }

        public Contaminacao(string cor, string descricao)
        {
            Cor = cor;
            Descricao = descricao;
        }
    }
```

Contaminacao_Regra

```
public class Contaminacao_Regra
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter entre {2} a {1} caracteres")]
        [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public int Anterior_ContaminacaoId { get; set; }
        public int Proxima_ContaminacaoId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Contaminação Antes")]
        [ForeignKey("Anterior_ContaminacaoId")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo {0} é obrigatório")]
        public virtual Contaminacao Contaminacao_Anterior { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Contaminação Depois")]
        [ForeignKey("Proxima_ContaminacaoId")]
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo {0} é obrigatório")]
        public virtual Contaminacao Contaminacao_Proxima { get; set; }

        public Contaminacao_Regra()
        {
        }

        public Contaminacao_Regra(int id, string descricao, Contaminacao contaminacao_Anterior, Contaminacao contaminacao_Proxima)
        {
            Id = id;
            Descricao = descricao;
            Contaminacao_Anterior = contaminacao_Anterior;
            Contaminacao_Proxima = contaminacao_Proxima;
        }

        public Contaminacao_Regra(int id, Contaminacao contaminacao_Anterior, Contaminacao contaminacao_Proxima)
        {
            Id = id;
            Contaminacao_Anterior = contaminacao_Anterior;
            Contaminacao_Proxima = contaminacao_Proxima;
        }

        public Contaminacao_Regra(string descricao, Contaminacao contaminacao_Anterior, Contaminacao contaminacao_Proxima)
        {
            Descricao = descricao;
            Contaminacao_Anterior = contaminacao_Anterior;
            Contaminacao_Proxima = contaminacao_Proxima;
        }
    }
```

As I have to put two fk from the same entity, I made this configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //Regra de Contaminação
            modelBuilder.Entity<Contaminacao_Regra>()
                   .HasOne(m => m.Contaminacao_Anterior)
                   .WithMany(t => t.Anterior_Contaminacao_Regras)
                   .HasForeignKey(m => m.Anterior_ContaminacaoId)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Contaminacao_Regra>()
                   .HasOne(m => m.Contaminacao_Proxima)
                   .WithMany(t => t.Proxima_Contaminacao_Regras)
                   .HasForeignKey(m => m.Proxima_ContaminacaoId)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            //Transferencia Produto
            modelBuilder.Entity<TransferenciaProduto>()
                   .HasOne(m => m.EstoqueOrigem)
                   .WithMany(t => t.Origem_TransferenciaProduto)
                   .HasForeignKey(m => m.EstoqueOrigemId)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            modelBuilder.Entity<TransferenciaProduto>()
                   .HasOne(m => m.EstoqueDestino)
                   .WithMany(t => t.Destino_TransferenciaProduto)
                   .HasForeignKey(m => m.EstoqueDestinoId)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            //Ordem Produção
            modelBuilder.Entity<OrdemProducao>()
                   .HasOne(m => m.Sequencia)
                   .WithOne(i => i.OrdemProducao)
                   .HasForeignKey<OrdemProducao_Sequencia>(b => b.OrdemProducaoId);

            // retira delete cascata
            var cascadeFKs = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .SelectMany(t => t.GetForeignKeys())
                .Where(fk => !fk.IsOwnership && fk.DeleteBehavior == DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            foreach (var fk in cascadeFKs)
                fk.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }
```

After I made these settings, I had the error I mentioned above. This same problem was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420370/cant-use-migrations-in-ef-core-42p07-relation-aspnetroles-already-exists), but it didn't help me much.

Remembering that the error occurs only when the bank already exists.

does anyone know how to solve ???

UPDATE

[image]

FK_IdCorAntes and FK_IdCorDepois is Fk from 'Contaminacao'