# DOTNET Core migration problems

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

My ApplicationDbContext class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }
    }
```

first time when `dotnet ef migrations add Intial` it creates the identity tables in the cs file and running `dotnet ef database update` works fine.

After adding the following DbSet

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
```

`dotnet ef migrations add Second` works fine but running `dotnet ef database update` shows error.

```
Build started...Build succeeded.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (16ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE "AspNetRoles" (
          "Id" text NOT NULL,
          "Name" character varying(256) NULL,
          "NormalizedName" character varying(256) NULL,
          "ConcurrencyStamp" text NULL,
          CONSTRAINT "PK_AspNetRoles" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
      );
Failed executing DbCommand (16ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "AspNetRoles" (
    "Id" text NOT NULL,
    "Name" character varying(256) NULL,
    "NormalizedName" character varying(256) NULL,
    "ConcurrencyStamp" text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_AspNetRoles" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P07: relation "AspNetRoles" already exists
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 42P07
    MessageText: relation "AspNetRoles" already exists
    File: heap.c
    Line: 1155
    Routine: heap_create_with_catalog
42P07: relation "AspNetRoles" already exists
```

Am I missing something or I need a separate DbContext class which I don't want?

Comment: Have you checked the generated migrations? Based on exception i would say that for some reason EF either generated "full" migation for your `Second` or tries to apply first one again (check for migrations table and entry with id of your first one being there).

Comment: Additionally, check if _EFMigrations table exists and is populated with name of first migration

Comment: @GuruStron - Yes it is generating full migration for some reason though the Initial migration entry is available in the _EFMigrations table

Comment: Did this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420370/cant-use-migrations-in-ef-core-42p07-relation-aspnetroles-already-exists

Comment: No @mahesh_b my issue is slightly different